# How to get int Id of a Radio Button from its String name

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm making an Android app as part of my University project, and I want to know how do I get the Radio Button Id (int value) if I have its resource name as a string, which I get as follows:

```
String resName = getResources()
.getResourceEntryName(optionGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

Its because when a user returns back to this activity, his previously selected radio button has to be shown, using the check() method like this:

```
optionGroup.check(rBtnId);
```

I did think about storing the Radio Button Id itself, but I need the string value elsewhere in the app, and require the int Id only here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post one such String name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

[getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection for that:

```
public static int getId(String name) {
    try {
        Field idField = R.id.getDeclaredField(variableName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } 
}
```